Patio light string shows voltage though unplugged
my patio light string has stopped working. I have Unplugged all power to the string but the voltage detector still shows voltage in the string.  How can this be?

A high-impedance voltage detector can pick up weak induced voltage. Even touching one to an unplugged device can show AC voltage.

Please explain how you have "cut power" to the string. Unplug it? Flip the breaker for the outlet it's plugged into?

The string is unplugged

the string is acting as an antenna
